# Textview in ConstraintLayout not resizing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView in a ConstraintLayout that floats over an image, and is styled to look like a badge. The text view uses `wrap_content` and sometimes has 2 letters, sometimes 3. Sometimes the TextView needs to be updated. When this happens, the container for the TextView does not dynamically resize. This means that if the new text is 3 characters when it was 2 before, it now looks too big and if it is now 2 characters when it was 3 it clips the text.

How can I get the TextView to resize appropriately?

TextView in question is called `@id/attendance` i the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/image_holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        tools:background="@color/accent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/first_name"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="@color/dark_gray"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:shadow="false" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attendance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:minWidth="15dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        tools:text="100"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="20dp"
        tools:background="@color/green_complete"
        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Suzie"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Cue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Section of code where view is inflated and assigned. This is called when the view is first created and also when it is updated. The TextView in question is `gradeText`

```
public View getView(View existingView, final StudentAssignmentGrade item) {

            final StudentGrade grade = item.getGrade();

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (existingView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                existingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_view_grading, staggeredGridView, false);

                holder.firstNameText = (TextView) existingView.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
                holder.lastNameText = (TextView) existingView.findViewById(R.id.last_name);
                holder.studentImage = (CircularImageView) existingView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                //This is the textView
                holder.gradeText = (TextView) existingView.findViewById(R.id.attendance);


                existingView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) existingView.getTag();
            }

            //set other TextViews


            if (item.getGrade().getMark() != null) {
                holder.gradeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                String formattedMark = "";

                if(grade.getMark() != null)
                    formattedMark = grade.getMark().replaceAll("\\..*$", "");

                if(formattedMark.isEmpty())
                    formattedMark = "?";

                holder.gradeText.setText(" " + formattedMark + " ");

                holder.studentImage.setBorderColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.studentImage.setBorderWidth(2);
            } else {
                holder.gradeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                holder.studentImage.setBorderColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                holder.studentImage.setBorderWidth(2);
            }


            CourseGradeDisplay.PerformanceLevel performanceLevel = null;

            float gradePercent = item.getGrade().getPercentageEarned();
            final CourseGradeDisplay gradeDisplay = courseGradeDisplays.get(item.getCourseId());

            if(gradeDisplay != null && gradePercent >= 0.0f) {
                for (CourseGradeDisplay.PerformanceLevel level : gradeDisplay.getPerformanceLevels()) {
                    if (gradePercent >= level.getMinRange() && gradePercent <= level.getMaxRange()) {
                        performanceLevel = level;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            int iconColor = R.color.black;

            if(performanceLevel != null) {
                switch (performanceLevel.getColor()) {
                    case 4: iconColor = R.color.grade_output_blue; break;
                    case 3: iconColor = R.color.grade_output_green; break;
                    case 2: iconColor = R.color.grade_output_yellow; break;
                    case 1: iconColor = R.color.grade_output_red; break;
                    default: iconColor = R.color.black;

                }
            }


            //set icon and color
            Drawable iconDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_corner_bg);
            iconDrawable.setColorFilter(new
                    PorterDuffColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(iconColor), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
            holder.gradeText.setBackgroundDrawable(iconDrawable);





            holder.studentImage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                ...
            });


            try {
                // .. set more listeners ...
            }
            return existingView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that once a view is added to a ViewGroup you cannot expect it to resize itself properly when data changes and wrap_content is in play. The solution came in the form of this wonderful static helper class someone else wrote. It is here: https://github.com/ea167/android-layout-wrap-content-updater